# Xpath of container with same class name

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a selenium test for a java applicaton that creates new id after every login session, so I can't find an element using ID's.

How do I find the second or third class in xpath that has the same name without using ID's

```
<div class="aui_FieldLayout_InputContainer">
<textarea id="gwt-uid-1601" class="aui-TextAreaInput printable" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="aui_FieldLayout_InputContainer">
<textarea id="gwt-uid-1602" class="aui-TextAreaInput printable" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="aui_FieldLayout_InputContainer">
<textarea id="gwt-uid-1603" class="aui-TextAreaInput printable" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do it. One option would be to find the elements by xpath and check that `id` attribute starts with `gwt-uid-`:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath('//textarea[starts-with(@id, "gwt-uid-")]'))
```

Another option would be to rely on the `textarea`'s containers:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath('//div[@class="aui_FieldLayout_InputContainer"]/textarea'))
```

There are certainly other ways to do it, which one is more reliable and preferred depends on the page structure, the uniqueness of attribute names and values etc.

Hope that helps.